# How to back trace a yield in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I am working with an existing Rails application. What's the best way of decomposing the application?

If I start in **layouts/application.html.erb** I'll see one or more **<%yield%>** statements. How can I easily step back from a presented view in the browser to the underlying code that builds the yields? ie: without reading through the code in every view.

---

It's not really what I am looking for in this question, but it will perhaps help someone else looking for help on Rails. I have for some time been using the **rails-footnotes** gem. It adds a footer to the page which has all sorts of useful information: instance variables, view information and even SQL statements with timing.

gem 'rails-footnotes' to install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the debugger is too complicated, and you're looking for more of a trace file, you can probably get by using the default logging output. For example, when making a request, output similar to the following is output by default:

```
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-27 17:52:16 -0600
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML       
  Rendered sessions/create.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
  Rendered application/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered application/_wrapper.html.erb (54.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 150ms (Views: 150.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

As you can see, the output contains the controller and action that were accessed (`SessionsController#create`), as well as the various partials that were rendered for the request (`Rendered sessions/create.html.erb within layouts/application`, for example).

If you are looking for something between that simplicity, and the complexity of the debugger, you may wish to try something like [rack-bug](https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug) or [mini-profiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby) ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler?view=asciicast)).

It may be that what you are looking for is simply a good IDE. Some rails experts may scoff at the idea of using an IDE, but I think that they can provide many advantages to novices and experts alike. In your case, you could probably benefit from being able to easily set a beakpoint and visually single-step through your code as it executes, inspecting variable contents along the way. I really enjoy [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), and would recommend it unreservedly (not free, but has free trial and totally worth the expense).

Comment: Hi Brad thanks for your post. rack-bug looks pretty good... except like many Gems it appears out of date. I'll have a go at installing it.

Comment: Right on, I didn't realize you were already using rails-footnotes, which is similar. Another similar option is http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler?view=asciicast - good luck.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect this discussion, as well as some additional thoughts that occurred to me since posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ruby debugger.

Assuming you're using Ruby 1.9.3 (please respond if you're not), you imply do the following:

- In your Gemfile, include: `gem 'debugger'`
- Run `bundle` after saving
- In your controller (or wherever you want to use it) place line `debugger` where you want code execution to stop.

Now hit your app through the browser and look into where you started the server and you should see the debug prompt.

You may have to start your server in debug mode, which you do as follows:

```
rails server --debugger
```

[Rails Guide - Debugging Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That sounds harder than looking though the view code. I was looking for a "1 stop shop" where I could start with the rendered view and easily see what has been used to build it.

Comment: Sorry, there really aren't any "1 stop shops" that I can think of that do specifically what you're asking, they all require some bit of work on your end.

Answer (score 1):

How about just adding `raise Exception` wherever it is in the code that you want to break.  This will generate a stack trace.

It's a pretty crude solution -- I tend to use the logger as @BradWerth suggests -- indeed, just the Rails log is often enough.  The debugger is useful in certain situations where you really need to dig deep, but in my experience it's a royal pain to set up and use :-)